# React: How to import and filter rendered inputs into a component?

Tags: reactjs

I want to import and filter rendered inputs into a component. My main `App.jsx` contains the rendered inputs and I want to import these into my `SearchBar.jsx`, filter, export and render in `App.jsx`. In addition, as I am new to React, I feel this may be a long way and wonder what is the best practice?

`renderReminders` method in class `App` of `App.jsx`:

```
  renderReminders() {
    //access our reminders

    const {reminders} = this.props;

    return (
      <ul className="list-group col-sm-4">
        {
          reminders.map(reminder => {
            return (
              <li key={ reminder.id } className="list-group item">
                <div className="list-item">{ reminder.text }
                  <div className="list-item delete-button"
                   onClick={() => this.deleteReminder(reminder.id)}>
                     &#x2715;
                  </div>
                </div>
              </li>
            )
          })
         }
      </ul>
    )
   }
```

SearchBar.jsx:

```
export class SearchView extends Component{
    //initialize the component
    constructor(){
        super();
        this.state={
            input:""
        }
        autoBind (this);
    }
    //handle event change in the input
    handleChange(event){
        this.setState({
            input:event.target.value
            });

    }
    //render the filtered list from input 
    render(){
        let filterReminders=addReminder.filter(word=>{
            if ( word.indexOf(this.state.input) !== -1){
                return true;
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

Create another Component (`Reminders`) that knows how to render a list of reminders. Then, pass `App`'s the reminders to `SearchView` as props, filter them, and pass along to the `Reminders` element rendered in the `SearchView`.

```
class App extends Component {
  render() {
    const reminders = //get reminders;
    return (
      <div>
        <SearchView reminders={reminders} />
      <div>
    );
  }
}

class SearchView extends Component {
  render() {
    const filterReminders= this.props.reminders.filter(r => /*some filter*/);
    return (
      <div>
        <Reminders reminders={filteredReminders}/>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

const Reminders = ({ reminders }) => (
  // render reminders
);
```

If you want to have your reminders rendered alongside your search view instead of embedded in the search view:

```
class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { searchValue: '' };
  }

  render() {
    const reminders = // get reminders;
    const filteredReminders = reminders
      .filter(reminder => /* some filter */);
    const { searchValue } = this.state;

    return (
      <div>
        <SearchView value={searchValue} onChange={evt => this.setState({ searchValue: evt.target.value }) />
        <Reminders reminders={filteredReminders}/>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

const SearchView = ({ value, onChange }) => (
  <input value={value} onChange={onChange}/>
);

const Reminders = ({ reminders }) => (
  // render reminders
);
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. The App.jsx renders the reminders, do i need take that out to Reminders.jsx, render them there or take the list of reminders from App.jsx and pass them to SearchView, filter, and export to App.jsx? I didn't understand why we need (another) Reminders component. I appreciate if you can explain how the list of reminders are exported as variables to another component. Thanks again.

Comment: From your answer i see that SearchView component could be in App.jsx. So, there is no need to export the rendered (user input) reminders?

Comment: Without seeing your app, it is difficult to make recommendations on its structure. What I was trying to do was demonstrate how you can isolate the roles of each component in your app. In my example, `App` gets reminders and renders them in a `SearchView`. `SearchView` maintains an input value, filters a set of reminders based on that input, and renders the filtered reminders. `Reminders` renders a list of reminders.

Comment: If you want `App` to render the filtered reminders, then you need to rethink the roles of your components. In this case, `App` renders a `SearchView`, maintains an input value received from its `SearchView`, filters a list of reminders based on that input value, and renders the filtered reminders. `SearchView` renders an input and conveys changes of the input value to a handler function. `Reminders` still renders a list of reminders.